# PHP and XPath get distinct attribute by condition

Tags: php, xpath

I'm using PHP to parse XML and would like to use XPATH to return a unique section value based on a system and front value condition.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<language>
    <phrase section="Url" system="0" front="1" data="_URL_M1">invoice</phrase>
    <phrase section="Url" system="0" front="1" data="_URL_M2">view</phrase>
    <phrase section="Invoice" system="1" front="0" data="_MOD_IM1">System1</phrase>
    <phrase section="Invoice" system="1" front="0" data="_MOD_IM2">System2</phrase>
    <phrase section="Invoice" system="0" front="1" data="_MOD_IM3">Front1</phrase>
    <phrase section="Invoice" system="0" front="1" data="_MOD_IM4">Front2</phrase>
    <phrase section="Invoice" system="1" front="1" data="_MOD_IM5">System and Front</phrase>
</language>
```

So I have section `Url` which is only displayed where front = 1 and section `Invoice` which is displayed where front = 1 and where front and system (both) = 1. Sections need to be displayed distinctly.

PHP:

```
$xmlel = simplexml_load_file(BASEPATH . self::langdir . $flag . "/" . $filename . ".xml");

$query_system = '/language/phrase[@system="1" and @front="0" and not(@section = preceding-sibling::phrase/@section)]/@section';

$query_front = '/language/phrase[@system="0" and @front="1" and not(@section = preceding-sibling::phrase/@section)]/@section';

$query_both = '/language/phrase[@system="1" and @front="1" and not(@section = preceding-sibling::phrase/@section)]/@section';
```

With current code I am getting this:

System: `$xmlel->xpath($query_system)`

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [section] => Invoice
            )

    )
)
```

Front: `$xmlel->xpath($query_front)`

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [section] => Url
            )

    )
)
```

Both: `$xmlel->xpath($query_both)`

```
Array
(
)
```

What I want to achieve:

System:

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [section] => Invoice
            )

    )
)
```

Front:

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [section] => Url
            )

    )
)
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [section] => Invoice
            )

    )
)
```

Both:

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [section] => Invoice
            )

    )
)
```

How can I get distinct `section` 

where: `system` = 1, 

where `front` = 1 

and where `system` and `front` = 1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I came to the conclusion that I also need to condition preceding-sibling:

```
$query_system = '/language/phrase[@system="1" and @front="0" and not(@section = preceding-sibling::*[@system="1" and @front="0"]/@section)]/@section';
$query_front = '/language/phrase[@system="0" and @front="1" and not(@section = preceding-sibling::*[@system="0" and @front="1"]/@section)]/@section';
$query_both = '/language/phrase[@system="1" and @front="1" and not(@section = preceding-sibling::*[@system="1" and @front="1"]/@section)]/@section';
```